# Error while zabbix installation

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

Below are the steps i folowed while zabbix installation:

1. tar -zxf zabbix-1.8.tar.gz
2. Create the Zabbix database in mysql
3. yum install iksemel-devel
4. yum install net-snmp-devel
5. ./configure --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --with-net-snmp --with-jabber --with-libcurl

Then when i am executing : `make install` then i am seeing the below exception. Please help me figuring out the problem. Thanks.

```
../../../include/zbxdb.h:67:20: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
../../../include/zbxdb.h:68:21: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
../../../include/zbxdb.h:69:27: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../../include/db.h:25,
from db.c:22:
../../../include/zbxdb.h:71: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../../../include/zbxdb.h:174: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../../../include/zbxdb.h:175: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../../../include/zbxdb.h:177: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'zbx_db_fetch'
In file included from db.c:22:
../../../include/db.h:546: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../../../include/db.h:548: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../../../include/db.h:549: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'DBfetch'
../../../include/db.h:586: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'MYSQL_ROW'
db.c:34: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
db.c: In function 'zbx_db_connect':
db.c:119: error: 'conn' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:119: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
db.c:119: error: for each function it appears in.)
db.c:121: error: 'CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:145: error: 'CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:146: error: 'CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:147: error: 'CR_CONNECTION_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:148: error: 'CR_SERVER_LOST' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:149: error: 'ER_SERVER_SHUTDOWN' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:150: error: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:151: error: 'ER_ILLEGAL_GRANT_FOR_TABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:152: error: 'ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:153: error: 'ER_UNKNOWN_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c: In function 'zbx_db_close':
db.c:350: error: 'conn' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c: At top level:
db.c:409: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
db.c: In function 'zbx_db_vexecute':
db.c:656: error: 'conn' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:668: error: 'CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:669: error: 'CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:670: error: 'CR_CONNECTION_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:671: error: 'CR_SERVER_LOST' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:672: error: 'ER_SERVER_SHUTDOWN' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:673: error: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:674: error: 'ER_ILLEGAL_GRANT_FOR_TABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:675: error: 'ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c:676: error: 'ER_UNKNOWN_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
db.c: At top level:
db.c:825: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
db.c:1124: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
db.c:1139: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'zbx_db_fetch'
make[3]: *** [db.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/xyy/zabbix-1.8.4/src/libs/zbxdb'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/xyz/zabbix-1.8.4/src/libs'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/xyz/zabbix-1.8.4/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

**EDIT DETAILS:**
As per one comment i tried installing mysql-devel i.e. `yum install mysql-devel` but i got below error:

```
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: mysql = 5.1.69-1.el6_4
           Installed: mysql-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               mysql = 5.5.28-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
               mysql = 5.1.66-2.el6_3
           Available: mysql-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               mysql = 5.1.67-1.el6_3
           Available: mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               mysql = 5.1.69-1.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Can somebody please help me in getting rid of the  situation. Thanks.

**EDIT details:** Below are the things which i find when i do fire the command: `ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1926 Jun 26  2012 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  637 Jun 26  2012 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  626 Jun 26  2012 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2593 Jun 26  2012 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  475 Aug 19  2012 ZabbixZone.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1056 Nov  5  2012 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  957 Aug 21  2012 epel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  739 Nov 13  2010 mirrors-rpmforge
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  717 Nov 13  2010 mirrors-rpmforge-extras
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  728 Nov 13  2010 mirrors-rpmforge-testing
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  633 Nov 13  2010 remi.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1113 Aug 21  2012 rpmforge.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  401 Jan 25 23:10 zabbix.repo
```

**EDIT details:** At last the issue got solved and many thanks to [Michael Tabolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901154/error-while-zabbix-installation?noredirect=1#comment24447077_16901154) and [Joao Figueiredo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901154/error-while-zabbix-installation/16921347?noredirect=1#16921347). :

> **cat  /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo**

and found out that remi repo was disabled. Then edited it through

> **vi /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo.**

changed **`enabled=0`** to **`enabled=1`**. Then did a **`yum install mysql-devel`** and it worked.

Comment: you have installed mysql from remi repo which is probably disabled now. yum is trying to install mysql-devel from centos updates repo and fails because the versions don't match. install mysql-dev from remi repo:
`yum --enable-repo=remi install mysql-devel`
or downgrade to official mysql:
`yum downgrade mysql`
`yum install mysql-devel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in  installing zabbix, but in compiling it. You are missing the mysql headers. `yum install mysql-devel`
However, I really don't know why you try to compile. Also the old version. For el distros (RHEL, CentOS, Scientific) use the EPEL repo, it has the 2.0 there.
Edit: link to EPEL repo as requested, follow the instructions for your distribution:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL
then `yum list zabbix2*` andinstall what you need.

and your sql files are here

```
rpm -ql zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.5-1.el6.x86_64 | grep create
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.5/create
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.5/create/data.sql
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.5/create/images.sql
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.5/create/schema.sql
```

Comment: i could not find a direct installation guide. Could you please give me a link. Thanks!

Comment: i have edited the question. I could not follow how to link to EPEL repo. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer and now i think it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Trying,
your way overcomplicating.

Why would you try to compile such an obsolete version?
The last time I've compiled 1.8 was about an year ago.

Though you don't specify your distro, you can follow up from here,
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/installation/install_from_packages

Comment: Thanks a lot atleast for replying. I lost hope. I already tried the link that u have given. But when i comes to the step **Creating initial database** i am not able to find the directory `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-2.0.4/create`. Can you please help resolving this. I would rate myself as starter in UNIX world. Thanks.

Comment: Don't lose hope. You never mentioned your distro..
If don't have a clue where some file is located into your file structure, you can just
updatedb (needs root privileges)
locate 'path_you_are_looking_for'

for instance,
locate zabbix-server-mysql-2
will point you to where the create dir is.